# Deselect all radiobuttons when they are under same variable

Tags: python, tkinter

In tkinter I am creating radiobuttons with for loops so they all have the same variable to call methods on

```
for z in posOne: #chief
    r = Radiobutton(new, text=z, variable=chief, value=z, indicatoron=0, width=15) 
    r.place(x=60, y=chiefY)
    chiefY += 25

for z in posTwo: #assistant chief
    r = Radiobutton(new, text=z, variable=asChief, value=z, indicatoron=0, width=15) 
    r.place(x=240, y=asChiefY)
    asChiefY += 25

for z in posThree: #captain
    r = Radiobutton(new, text=z, variable=cap, value=z, indicatoron=0, width=15) 
    r.place(x=420, y=capY)
    capY += 25

for z in posFour: #first lieutenant
    r = Radiobutton(new, text=z, variable=lieut, value=z, indicatoron=0, width=15) 
    r.place(x=600, y=lieutY)
    lieutY += 25
```

When I call `r.deselect()` it only deselects the last radiobutton made. How can I deselect all of them with the for loop set up that I have already?

Comment: r can only hold one value at a time unless it points to a list.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix my problem by storing each radiobutton in a list within the for loops and than calling a for loop to deselect everything in that list

```
     arr = []
     for z in posOne: #chief
        r = Radiobutton(new, text=z, variable=chief, value=z, indicatoron=0, width=15) 
        r.place(x=60, y=chiefY)
        chiefY += 25
        arr.append(r)

    for z in posTwo: #assistant chief
        r = Radiobutton(new, text=z, variable=asChief, value=z, indicatoron=0, width=15) 
        r.place(x=240, y=asChiefY)
        asChiefY += 25
        arr.append(r)

    for z in posThree: #captain
        r = Radiobutton(new, text=z, variable=cap, value=z, indicatoron=0, width=15) 
        r.place(x=420, y=capY)
        capY += 25
        arr.append(r)

    for z in posFour: #first lieutenant
        r = Radiobutton(new, text=z, variable=lieut, value=z, indicatoron=0, width=15) 
        r.place(x=600, y=lieutY)
        lieutY += 25
        arr.append(r)

    for x in arr:
        x.deselect()
```